# Ajax not sending multiple php variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to visit a url using ajax, having 2 parameteres. My cureent script does not show any response.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#ocountClc").click(function (){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://localhost/xyz/abc.php",
      data: { R33te0x: <?php echo $vara; ?>, tag: <?php echo $varb; ?> },
       success: function() {
             alert('done');
        }
      });
  });     
});
```

On the PHP:

```
echo $_POST['R33te0x'];
```

Comment: What is the rendered JavaScript? to the php vars need quoting?

Comment: What response code does your ajax return?

Comment: How are you examining the response?  All your code does is call an `alert()`.

Comment: You better put your data from the PHP code in data object before the ajax post, check if it arrived as expected and then send it to the ajax data.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try your `POST` request like this ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#ocountClc").click(function (){
    $.post("http://localhost/xyz/abc.php",{"R33te0x": "<?php echo $vara; ?>", 
       "tag": "<?php echo $varb; ?>"},function(response) 
    {
            alert("done");
            console.log(response); //see what response you are getting


    });
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an issue with your json:

you forgot to surround the values of data inside quotes `""`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#ocountClc").click(function (){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://localhost/xyz/abc.php",
      data: { R33te0x: "<?php echo $vara; ?>", tag: "<?php echo $varb; ?>" },
       success: function() {
             alert('done');
        }
      });
  });     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put some quotes around the R33te0x and tag. I believe without them it's thinking those are variables.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ocountClc").click(function (){
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/xyz/abc.php",
        data: { 'R33te0x': <?php echo $vara; ?>, 'tag': <?php echo $varb; ?> },
        success: function() {
          alert('done');
        }
      });
  });     
});
```